# How do I create a column that auto generates a number in sequence?

Tags: list, database

There are multiple users key-ing information regarding candidates on our Recruitment Database. However, I want a **"Candidate number"** field automatically generated every time a new line item is created. How do I do this? And how do I make this Candidate Number field, my "main" field?

Comment: There are several similiar questions in this site. e.g. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88340/how-to-auto-populate-a-list-column-with-a-sequential-number

Answer (score 0):

you can create a "Candidate number" calculated SharePoint column with the formula

> =CONCATENATE(Col1,[ID])

or using

> =Text[ID]